# Concatenation & conditions in php

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, concatenation

I'm learning PHP and i'm trying to show an " €" when and only when $autocollant_total_ht_custom isset.

This is what i wrote :

> ```
>   $euro = " €";
>
>   if (isset($autocollant_total_ht_custom)) {
>     $autocollant_total_ht_custom = $autocollant_total_ht_custom . $euro;
>   } else echo " ";
> ```

However my " €" is always showing even when $autocollant_total_ht_custom is not set.

I spent 75 minutes on it, trying and failing again and again despite researching.

I also tried with !is_null, !is_empty with the same result.

I'm fairly certain that my logic isn't wrong but the way to do it is.

Anyone to the rescue?

Have a nice Saturday everyone !

Mike.

**Edit 1:**

**A little visual aid [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0bSZ.png)**

My goal was to only show the content of a cell if there was indeed something in it. By default i could see 0 in the empty cells.

> ```
>   if (!$autocollant_total_ht_lot10) {
>     $autocollant_total_ht_lot10 = " ";
>   } else echo "error ";
>
>   if (!$autocollant_total_ht_lot20) {
>     $autocollant_total_ht_lot20 = " ";
>   } else echo " ";
>
>   if (!$autocollant_total_ht_lot50) {
>     $autocollant_total_ht_lot50 = " ";
>   } else echo " ";
>
>   if (!$autocollant_total_ht_custom) {
>     $autocollant_total_ht_custom = " ";
>   } else echo " ";
> ```

I know my code must look primitive but it works and i don't see it making a conflict with what we are trying to achieve in the initial question.

Then, as asked, this is what i'm writing in the table row and table data :

```
  <tr>
    <td class=table_align_left>A partir de 100</td>
    <td><?php echo $autocollant_prix ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $autocollant_custom?></td>
    <td><?php echo $autocollant_total_ht_custom?> </td>
  </tr>
```

So in short, i'm trying to not show anything if there's no value to be shown (which is currently working) and then adding a " €" after the variable is there's something to be shown.

**Edit 2 :**

**My primitive code :** [my_code](https://3v4l.org/iMR7L)

**Edit 3 :**

The $autocollant_total_ht_custom is already conditioned to be shown earlier in this statement :

> ```
>   } elseif($autocollant_quantité >= 90 && $autocollant_quantité <= 99){
>       $autocollant_quantité_lot50 = 2;
>   } elseif($autocollant_quantité >= 100 && $autocollant_quantité <= 1000){
>       $autocollant_custom = $autocollant_quantité;
>   } else echo "entrée invalide";
>
>
>
>   $autocollant_total_ht_custom = $autocollant_prix * $autocollant_custom;
>   $autocollant_total_ht_lot10 = $autocollant_prix_lot10 * $autocollant_quantité_lot10;
>   $autocollant_total_ht_lot20 = $autocollant_prix_lot20 * $autocollant_quantité_lot20;
>   $autocollant_total_ht_lot50 = $autocollant_prix_lot50 * $autocollant_quantité_lot50;
>
>   $pointeuse_total_ht = $pointeuse_prix * $pointeuse_quantité;
>   $pointeuse_autocollant_offert = $pointeuse_quantité * 10;
>   $pointeuse_autocollant_offert_total_ht = $pointeuse_autocollant_offert * $autocollant_prix;
>   $pointeuse_autocollant_offert_total_ht = $pointeuse_autocollant_offert * $autocollant_prix;
> ```

I posted my code if that can help.

Mike.

Comment: Your if statement is fine so you must be setting the variable earlier in your code. Although you're not sharing where you echo the result. Can you share more of the php

Comment: So I understand better, you only want $euro to be set as " €", if the Isset condition is true?

Comment: Not reproducible https://3v4l.org/SXGTj

Comment: Are you sure the behaviour you are looking for is provided by isset()? If a variable is set to null, false, zero or an empty string, it is still set.

Comment: Using the example above, https://3v4l.org/kcT29. isset returns true if the value is anything other than null. Unsure of the answer downvote as it seems to fit the requirments. switch the $autocollant_total_ht_custom at the top to see an example.

Answer (score -1):

```
//$autocollant_total_ht_custom = null;
$autocollant_total_ht_custom = "something that isnt null"; 
//if you switch the variable assignment above you will see it behaves as expected.
 $euro = "€";

  if (isset($autocollant_total_ht_custom)) 
  {         
    echo $autocollant_total_ht_custom = $autocollant_total_ht_custom . " " .$euro;
  } 
   else 
  {  
     //$autocollant_total_ht_custom wouldn't be set at all if we reach this point, this is why im un-sure what your requirements are. Nothing would be echoed.
     echo  $autocollant_total_ht_custom;
  }
```

Something like this maybe? It's hard to understand your exact requirements.

**IsSet** checks if a variable is set to *something* if its not null then it passes the test, and if you're manipulating strings at this variable then it will never be null, meaning the euro sign will always show up.

If the variable IS null then you fail the conditional test, hit else and echo nothing a null string.

If you can update your answer with what you would expect "$autocollant_total_ht_custom" to be set to, I can help better.

EDIT:

Seems to me you can simplify what you what, basically we are only concerned with echoing a string at all if there is something set, otherwise there's no point doing anything, so your checks could be as simple as

```
$autocollant_total_ht_lot10 = null;
$autocollant_total_ht_lot11 = "";
$autocollant_total_ht_custom = "1,000"; 
 $euro = "€";

if (isset($autocollant_total_ht_custom)) 
{         
  echo 'ht custom';
  echo TDFromString($autocollant_total_ht_custom, $euro);
} 

//notice this doesnt output anything because it isnt set
if (isset($autocollant_total_ht_lot10, $euro)) 
{         
  echo 'lot 10';
  echo TDFromString($autocollant_total_ht_lot10, $euro);
}

//notice this does because the string, while empty is something that isnt null
if (isset($autocollant_total_ht_lot11)) 
{     
  echo 'lot 11';
  echo TDFromString($autocollant_total_ht_lot11, $euro);
}
//lets set it to null and see what happens
$autocollant_total_ht_lot11 = null;
if (isset($autocollant_total_ht_lot11)) 
{     
  echo 'lot 11 AGAIN';
  echo TDFromString($autocollant_total_ht_lot11,  $euro);
}
//it doesnt get printed!

//create a function that takes the string in question, 
//and for the sake of your use case also the currency to output, 
//that way you could change 'euro' to 'currency' 
//and have the sign change based on what the value of the $currency 
//string is, eg $currency = "£"

function TDFromString($string, $currency)
{
  return '<td>' . $string . ' ' .$currency . '</td>';
}
```

Live example : https://3v4l.org/r5pKt

A more explicit example : https://3v4l.org/JtnoF

I added an extra echo to indicate (and newlines) which variable is being printed out you dont need it of course!

I'll just note the function name is a good example of a bad function name, as it not only returns a td around the string but also inserts the currency, you may want to name it a little better :)

EDIT EDIT:

A final edit outside the scope of your question, you should look into keeping your data in arrays and working on them instead.

Using the previous example we can reduce the code to just this !

```
    $autocollant_total_ht_lot10 = null;
    $autocollant_total_ht_lot11 = "";
    $autocollant_total_ht_lot12 = "2,0000000";
    $autocollant_total_ht_custom = "1,000"; 
     $euro = "€";
     //create an array, and stick all our strings in it, from now, if we need to do something to one of the strings(or all!), we do it through the array
    $arrayofLots = array($autocollant_total_ht_lot10, $autocollant_total_ht_lot11, $autocollant_total_ht_lot12, $autocollant_total_ht_custom);

   //go over each array 'entry' so the first time is '$autocollant_total_ht_lot10', then '$autocollant_total_ht_lot11' etc
    foreach ($arrayofLots as $lot)
    { 
        //and we've been over this bit :)
        //$lot is a variable we set so we have something to refer to for the individual array entry  we are on, we could just as easily name it anything else
        if (isset($lot)) 
        {         
          echo TDFromString($lot, $euro);
        } 
    }


function TDFromString($string, $currency)
{
  return '<td>' . $string . ' ' .$currency . '</td>';
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your time! I edited my post with more details.

Comment: Check my answer now, hopefully I've understood you correctly!

Comment: I think I understand your problem now, if you check the live example it might clear up your confusion!

Comment: Looks really great but how do i insert it in my <td></td>? Mike.

Comment: In the same line you echo what would be the contents of it out, but if its something you are doing often it would be better to make a function that takes a string and returns you a string wrapped in the td, ill update the post to show a simple example.

Comment: Saw your third edit, you are setting $autocollant_total_ht_custom to $autocollant_prix * $autocollant_custom, then if it isnt set(which it is, you just set it!)  you are setting it to an empty string, if it set you are just echoing an empty string, you then try to set $autocollant_total_ht_custom equal to itself further down, which of course is no use, it already knows what value it is!

From what I have read of your live example, my answer should help, you are confusing your checks and forcing yourself to do something with the string even if there is no need.

Answer (score -2):

Good day. It looks like you are missing the end brace

```
if (isset($autocollant_total_ht_custom)) {
    $autocollant_total_ht_custom = $autocollant_total_ht_custom . $euro;
} else { 
    echo " ";
}
```

Comment: You added two braces and they are not needed in this case.

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible. I can't imagine how unreadable the code would become in a large application. Good to know though. peace.